# SQL - combining multiple columns into 1 string in all possible unique permutations

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012, permutation

I have the following table:

```
AddressId     SubBuildingName    BuildingName    BuildingNumber   Postcode
12345         Flat 1             SomeBuilding    80               MK34 1PU
12346         Flat 2             SomeBuilding    80               MK34 1PU
12347         Flat 7             OtherBuilding   NULL             MK22 9IT
```

For each address, I need to combine **SubBuildingName, BuildingName and BuildingNumber** into 1 comma-separated string in all possible non-repetitive permutations as follows:

```
AddressId     AddressLine1
12345         Flat 1, SomeBuilding, 80
12345         Flat 1, 80, SomeBuilding 
12345         80, Flat 1, SomeBuilding
12345         80, SomeBuilding, Flat 1
12345         SomeBuilding, Flat 1, 80
12345         SomeBuilding, 80, Flat 1
12346         Flat 1, SomeBuilding, 80
12346         Flat 1, 80, SomeBuilding 
12346         80, Flat 1, SomeBuilding
12346         80, SomeBuilding, Flat 1
12346         SomeBuilding, Flat 1, 80
12346         SomeBuilding, 80, Flat 1
12347         Flat 7, OtherBuilding
12347         OtherBuilding, Flat 7
```

Comment: I'm having trouble understanding the need here. Why would you want such a result set?  I suppose you could create all possible permutations in different selects and union the results though...

Comment: The need is to calculate the possible permutations as described above. Of course I could hard-code 6 unions, but the more columns are involved the more permutations are possible, e.g. for combining 4 columns there are 24 permutations!

Comment: To those who voted to close because it's unclear what he's asking, I think it's quite clear what he's asking.  While what he's asking is strange, it's certainly clear.

Comment: Let me re-phrase @xQbert's comment.  What do plan to do with the permutations once you have them?

Comment: @xQbert, I can think of at least one possible use: suppose you had an ugly source of addresses, with the various fields in no particular order, and you wanted to make sure that you didn't already have that same address in some other order?

Comment: Why is the business need relevant here? The requirement is as described clearly above and I am not going to explain why I need to do this as this is not relevant to the question. I know some people may be curious, but that is not the point :)

Comment: @DanBracuk It's also quite clear that it displays no research effort.

Comment: How would we determine what columns are involved each time? (Missing info) You may be able to create a separate select for each Address and column, join this to some temp table having a row count equal to the number of columns involved and then create a join only on address ID between all the selects and joins to the temp table or one with a row count > columns involved and and then just concat the columns together.... but I can't see how to do this without either unions and knowing the columns or use dynamic SQL, still having to know columns involved.  A creative question to say the least.

Comment: @Kermit, while it is true that the question shows no effort to solve the problem on it's own, that's not one of the listed reasons to close a question.

Comment: @DanBracuk Actually, that has been deemed the most appropriate close reason for that purpose.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you know ahead of time which columns you want to use, you can use an `UNPIVOT` and multiple self-joins to achieve the all-permutations effect without having to write twenty-four statements, such as with the following:

```
DECLARE @Permutations TABLE (ID INT IDENTITY(1,1), v1 VARCHAR(10), v2 VARCHAR(10), v3 VARCHAR(10), v4 VARCHAR(10))

INSERT INTO @Permutations (v1, v2, v3, v4) VALUES ('a', 'b', 'c', 'd')
INSERT INTO @Permutations (v1, v2, v3, v4) VALUES ('w', 'x', 'y', 'z');

WITH alldata AS (
SELECT ID, Value, ValName 
FROM 
    @Permutations
UNPIVOT 
 (Value FOR ValName IN (v1, v2, v3, v4)) up
)

SELECT 
    one.ID AS AddressID, 
    one.Value + ',' + two.Value + ',' + three.Value + ',' + four.Value AS AddressLine1
FROM 
    alldata one
     INNER JOIN 
    alldata two ON 
        one.ID = two.ID AND 
        one.ValName <> two.ValName
     INNER JOIN 
    alldata three ON 
        one.ID = three.ID AND
        one.ValName <> three.ValName AND
        two.ValName <> three.ValName 
     INNER JOIN 
    alldata four ON 
        one.ID = four.ID AND
        one.ValName <> four.ValName AND
        two.ValName <> four.ValName AND
        three.ValName <> four.ValName
ORDER BY AddressID, AddressLine1
```

EDIT: reading comments posted since I started working on the code, I'm not clear whether the OP would be satisfied to see code like this (four statement for four columns as opposed to twenty-four UNIONs, five for five, etc.) or needs the entire thing to be dynamic.  This answer will only satisfy if you are looking for a technique to write minimal code without manually accounting for each possible permutation.

Comment: Perfect, this works for me (I had to change INNER JOINs to LEFT JOINs as some columns in my example may contain NULLs)

Answer (score 1):

By it's nature Union will do a distinct.  Coalesce is used to handle null values
and each statement handles the 6 different potential orders

```
SELECT AddressId, 
       CONCAT(coalesce(SubBuildingName,''), ', ',
              coalesce(BuildingName,''), ', ',
              coalesce(BuildingNumber,'')
       ) AS AddressLine1
FROM MyTable
UNION
SELECT AddressId, 
       CONCAT(coalesce(SubBuildingName,''), ', ',
              coalesce(BuildingNumber,''), ', ',
              coalesce(BuildingName,'')
       ) AS AddressLine1
FROM MyTable
UNION
SELECT AddressId, 
       CONCAT(coalesce(BuildingNumber,''), ', ',
              coalesce(BuildingName,''), ', ',
              coalesce(SubBuildingName,'')
       ) AS AddressLine1
FROM MyTable
UNION
SELECT AddressId, 
       CONCAT(coalesce(BuildingNumber,''), ', ',
              coalesce(SubBuildingName,''), ', ',
              coalesce(BuildingName,'')
       ) AS AddressLine1
FROM MyTable
UNION
SELECT AddressId, 
       CONCAT(coalesce(BuildingName,''), ', ',
              coalesce(SubBuildingName,''), ', ',
              coalesce(BuildingNumber,'')
       ) AS AddressLine1
FROM MyTable
UNION
SELECT AddressId, 
       CONCAT(coalesce(BuildingName,''), ', ',
              coalesce(BuildingNumber,''), ', ',
              coalesce(SubBuildingName,'')
       ) AS AddressLine1
FROM MyTable
```

Comment: As I commented above, I know I can do the Union - but perhaps my example above was too trivial to demonstrate why I did not want to go down the UNION route. For example, If there were 4 columns involved in producing all possible permutations, I would need to hand-code 24 unions! Is there not a more dynamic way of coding this?

Comment: There is dynamic SQL... but how would you know what COLUMNS are involved each time?

Comment: I know what columns are involved (4, but I only presented 3 in the example above for simplicity).